# Why I have to click twice to work my function?

Tags: angular

I made a function for pagination to change page:

```
onClick(number) {
    this.CustomersData.page(number);
    this.customers = this.CustomersData.customer;
    console.log(this.customers);
    console.log(this.CustomersData.customer);
}
```

> and here is the function that I called in onClick:

```
page(number) {
  this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers?page=' + (number), {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization',
      this.token.t)}).subscribe(r => {
      this.customer  = r;
      console.log(this.customer);
    });
}
```

> here I call onClick function in my template for pagination:

```
<ul class="pagination-custom text-right">
    <li class="pag-link"><a (click)="onClick(customers.meta.pagination.current_page - 1)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a></li>
    <li class="pag-link" *ngFor="let item of createRange(customers.meta.pagination.per_page); let i = index"
        >
      <a (click)="onClick(i)">{{i}}</a></li>
  <li class="pag-link"><a (click)="onClick(customers.meta.pagination.current_page + 1)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

here is the loop:

```
createRange(number) {
    const items: number[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      items.push(i);
    }
    return items;
  }
```

> Problem is that I have to click twice to move to another page.
>
> > and another problem is that in my console is showed that in my object nothing changed when it's called in the first function and in the third console is showed array that has to be for page from function page().
> >     If I understand correctly the first console has to be shown that what is called from function page().

Comment: I believe the problem occurs because the first time you click, you call your function that makes the API call which works, fine. You subscribe to it and assign the `this.customer` inside your `customerData` file, meaning it will wait for the request's response there, however the `this.customers = this.CustomersData.customer;` in your `onClick()` wont wait for all that, you assign it straight away. So it's only one click later that `CustomerData.customer` will be assigned.

Comment: can you help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: what can I do to make it only by one click

Comment: can you provide the content of this function ``createRange(customers.meta.pagination.per_page)``, if you can edit and update the code of your question by adding that.

Comment: yes, I made it.

Comment: I think you will need to trigger some change detection or change the reference of the data array you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  `this.customers = this.CustomersData.customer;` in the `onClick()` isn't waiting for the subscription inside your service to set the value of `this.CustomersData.customer`, so it will always be a click behind the actual data fetching.

Here are some possible fixes:

#### Behavior Subjects

If you want to keep your structure the same, I suggest you take a look at `BehaviorSubject`.
I created a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-simple-service-vzj7vp) to show you.

#### Seperate service and component

Another possibility would be for your page function not to subscribe to the `get()` request but return it instead. You could then subscribe to in in your `onClick()` like so:

```
onClick(number) {
    this.CustomersData.page(number).subscribe(res=> this.customers = res;);
}
```

Of course this is assuming you don't need that `customer` variable saved in your `CustomerData` service... if you do you can use `BehaviorSubject`

Hope any of these can help.

Comment: the last question please: if I change my object it will be changed in my template too? or I have to refresh the page for it

Comment: Assuming your customer object is binding in your template, it will change on it's own, just like in the stackblitz I linked

Comment: No worries! Feel free to mark the question as resolved if you're all good now, so other people know it's been solved